# Do I need to pass multiple variable in string concatenation

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

Can you please explain if I need to pass the variable multiple times for the string concatenation.

For eg.

```
String1 = "Hello"
String = "Good Morning"    
String2 = String + "%s, %s" % (String1, String1)
```

My question is, how do I pass `String1` just once?

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If your intended output is "HelloHelloHello" then yes

Comment: Where is the variable `String` defined?

Comment: @Kevin - Sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use the newer [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method, you can do:

```
String2 = String + "{0}, {0}".format(String1)
```

In fact, you should always prefer `str.format` over `%` formatting in modern Python.  The latter approach is pseudo-deprecated and will most likely be removed from a future version of the language.

Comment: The best solution would be: `String2 = "{0}{1}, {1}".format(String, String1)`

Comment: I was trying earlier to accept your answer but for some reasons, SO was not letting me. Now I could do it.